# Trying to understand how function call back works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am taking [jQuery.Atmosphere.js](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/blob/4af1424a04b1568a02bc14dce05e53b04dcf6ef6/modules/jquery/src/main/webapp/jquery/jquery.atmosphere.js) as an example, in this it has public function such as onMessage, onError etc. And when implementing this api i have done the following

```
var socket = $.atmosphere;
var request = new $.atmosphere.AtmosphereRequest();
request.onMessage = function(response) {
   // do what i want to do
 }
```

Here the onMessage will be trigger whenever the server pushes data to browser. I don't understand how request.onMessage(response) get notified which is outside the atmosphere api? I have looked in to the jQuery.Atmosphere.js and couldn't connect the dots how this works. I am not talking about websocket or server push or anything about atmosphere framework. I just want understand how javascript function callbacks work. Can anyone point me an example how function callbacks work or send me a link so i can dig in?

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. Provide the correct one.

Comment: It's being called here: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/blob/4af1424a04b1568a02bc14dce05e53b04dcf6ef6/modules/jquery/src/main/webapp/jquery/jquery.atmosphere.js#L2063

Comment: @Joseph Silber: `request.onMessage(response) { }` --- oh I see, it's correct but with redundant `{   }` - which may point to a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect, it should be:

```
request.onMessage = function(response) {
    // do what I want to do
};
```

As you can see, the `onMessage` property must be set to a function. When the Message event occurs on this object, the function will be called.  The [jQuery.Atmosphere.js](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/blob/4af1424a04b1568a02bc14dce05e53b04dcf6ef6/modules/jquery/src/main/webapp/jquery/jquery.atmosphere.js#L2063) code contains:

```
f.onMessage(response);
```

where `f` is its internal variable representing the `AtmosphereRequest` object. This function is called from `invokeFunction()`:

```
        function _invokeFunction(response) {
            _f(response, _request);
            // Global
            _f(response, jQuery.atmosphere);
        }
```

`_request` is a local variable in the `AtmosphereRequest` constructor, which contains all the state of this request object. This is part of Javascript object oriented programming; all uses of this `AtmosphereRequest` object have access to these internal state variables.

Comment: i am still not getting, can you explain with simple example without out using atmosphere code.

Comment: Not really, I don't have much expertise in this area. I suggest you google "Javascript object oriented programming".

Comment: actually i am also confused at this point `var socket = $.atmosphere;  ` is it referencing atmosphere object @Barmar

Comment: Yes, it's just another variable that refers to `$.atmosphere`. I don't know why he wrote it.